# Rendering OBJ pyopengl

Tags: python, opengl, rendering, opengl-compat

Pls I have been trying this for past few month but all prevail I tried alot of online resources to read and display OBJ file without MTl stuff all in vain, I write my codes still errors so I finally arrive at my self made code that can read obj file of any faces type e.g (v//vn)(v/by/vn)(v) I hope you understand this.
After I read the file I got no error but rendering with pyopengl I got no error but the object didn't show. Pls check my obj loader code, and the opengl code in the screen with the result in another screenshot.
Note I got no error I don't know if I wrote something wrong in the obj loader but pls check and help me pls.
OBJ code:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from pyopengltk import OpenGLFrame
class OBJ:
    def __init__(self,filename):
    self.faces = []
    self.vertices = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        #print(lines)
        if lines:
            for line in lines:
                if line[0] == 'v':
                    index1 = line.find(' ')
                    index2 = line.find(' ', index1+1)
                    index3 = line.find(' ', index2+1)

                    v1 = float(line[index1: index2])
                    v2 = float(line[index2: index3])
                    v3 = float(line[index3:])
                    self.vertices.append((v1,v2,v3))
                    #print(self.vertices)
        for line in open(filename, "r"):
            face = []
            texcoords = []
            norms = []
            if line.startswith('#'): continue
            values = line.split()
            #print(values)
            if not values: continue
            if values[0] == 'v':continue
            elif values[0] == 'vn':continue
            elif values[0] == 'vt':continue
            if values[0] == 'f':
                for v in values[1:]:
                    #print(len(v))
                    if len(v) == 4:
                        if ['/' for s in values[1:]]:
                            w = v.split('//')
                            face.append(int(w[0]))
                            norms.append(int(w[1]))
                            self.faces.extend(tuple((face, norms)))
                            #self.faces = [y for x in self.faces for y in x]
                            #print(self.faces)
                            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
                            glColor3f(0,1,1)
                            for surface in self.faces:
                                for vertex in surface:
                                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
                            glEnd
                        else:
                            self.faces.append(v)
                            glBegin(GL_QUADS)
                            glColor3f(0,1,1)
                            for surface in self.faces:
                                for vertex in surface:
                                    glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
                            glEnd
                            print(self.faces)
                    elif len(v) == 3:
                        w = v.split('/')
                        face.append(int(w[0]))
                        texcoords.append(int(w[1]))
                        norms.append(int(w[2]))
                        self.faces.append((face, norms, texcoord))
                        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
                        glColor3f(0,1,1)
                        for surface in self.faces:
                            for vertex in surface:
                                glVertex3fv(self.vertices[vertex])
                        glEnd
                        #print('v/vt/vn')
                        print(self.faces)
#to run this code just use file path to any obj file on your pc
#OBJ('filename_path')
```

Rendering code

```
import tkinter as tk
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from pyopengltk import OpenGLFrame
from obj import *

class frame(OpenGLFrame):

  def initgl(self):
        glViewport(0,0,self.width,self.height)
        glClearColor(0.902,0.902,1,0.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        #glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10)
        gluPerspective(60, self.width/self.height,0.1,100.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        
  
  def redraw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        OBJ('C:\\Users\\DANIEL\\Desktop\\v-cam\\me.obj')
        #that is what I did here obj suff
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(0,-10,0,0,0,0,1,0,20)
        

root = tk.Tk()
app = frame(root, width=900, height=600)
app.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=tk.YES)
app.mainloop()
```

[image: result screenshots]

Comment: Are you really loading the object each frame? It seems to me that you are perhaps missing parentheses after `glEnd`? Do not post the codes as an image, that does not help anybody. If you want proper help, make a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Ok pls refresh the page I have add every necessary details

Comment: No, you did not. The indentation in obj constructor is wrong. There's no info about how to compile the program - the first file is obj.py? And when I run it, i (obviously) get `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\DANIEL\\Desktop\\v-cam\\me.obj'`. The easier you make it for someone to run your code, the chance for someone to answer.  Did you try to add the parentheses? That's definitely a mistake and part of the problem.

Comment: *the better chance

Comment: To run the code you use OBJ(filename) in the rendering part!,. In the filename input any obj file path on your PC. Check the code you will see ive add it

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use the object loader which you have introduced in one of your previous questions ([Pyopengl reading obj file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62625561/pyopengl-reading-obj-file)).

Create an `OBJ` instance in `initgl`:

```py
self.obj =  OBJ('C:\\Users\\DANIEL\\Desktop\\v-cam\\me.obj')
```

And use [`glCallList`](http://pyopengl.sourceforge.net/documentation/manual-3.0/glCallList.html) to draw the mesh in `redraw`.

```py
glCallList(self.obj.gl_list)
```

Class `frame`:

```py
class frame(OpenGLFrame):

    def initgl(self):
        glViewport(0,0,self.width,self.height)
        glClearColor(0.902,0.902,1,0.0)
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
        glLoadIdentity()
        #glOrtho(-10,10,-10,10,-10,10)
        gluPerspective(60, self.width/self.height,0.1,100.0)
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        glEnable(GL_BLEND)
        glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        self.obj =  OBJ('C:\\Users\\DANIEL\\Desktop\\v-cam\\me.obj')
  
    def redraw(self):
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)
        #that is what I did here obj suff
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
        glLoadIdentity()
        gluLookAt(0,-10,0,0,0,0,1,0,20) 

        glCallList(self.obj.gl_list)
```